# SQL Subquery: subquery has too many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run a query that has 2 sub queries within it.  I'm trying to create a field called 'Delta Date' that subtracts minDate (from the 2nd query) from Date1.  Please help, I keep getting the error 'subquery has too many columns.'

```
SELECT Date1,                   #first query
     (Date1 - minDate) as Delta Date
    UNIQUE_ID 
FROM    panel
    WHERE (lower(criteria) LIKE lower(\'%criteria1%\'))
    AND UNIQUE_ID IN (


SELECT  min(Date1) as minDate,          #second query
    UNIQUE_ID 
FROM    panel
    WHERE (lower(criteria) LIKE lower(\'%criteria2%\'))
    AND Amount < 10000
    AND UNIQUE_ID IN ( SELECT   UNIQUE_ID        #third query
                           FROM     panel
                           WHERE    file_date > \'9/30/2015\'
/* AND additional logic to filter member purchases */
                           GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID
                           HAVING   count(AMOUNT) > 1 )

GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery which you marked as "#second query" returns minDate & UNIQUE_ID. This is the problem.

> UNIQUE_ID IN (SELECT  min(Date1) as minDate, UNIQUE_ID FROM ....

You need to put #second query in the FROM clause of first query.

Answer (score 0):

An `in` subquery should only have one column in this context:

```
UNIQUE_ID IN (
    SELECT UNIQUE_ID 
    FROM panel
    WHERE (lower(criteria) LIKE lower(\'%criteria1%\')) AND
           UNIQUE_ID IN (SELECT UNIQUE_ID 
                         FROM  panel
                         WHERE (lower(criteria) LIKE lower(\'%criteria2%\')) AND
                               Amount < 10000 AND
                               UNIQUE_ID IN (SELECT UNIQUE_ID 
                                             FROM  panel
                                             WHERE file_date > \'9/30/2015\'
    /* AND additional logic to filter member purchases */
                               GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID
                               HAVING   count(AMOUNT) > 1
                              )
                         GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID
                        )
    )
```

Your logic is quite hard to follow, and I'm not sure fixing the syntax creates a query that does what you want.

I think you can use window functions to similar effect.  I'm not sure what the exactly logic would be, but it would look like this:

```
SELECT Date1, UNIQUE_ID,
     (Date1 - MIN(DATE1) OVER (PARTITION BY UNIQUE_ID) ) as Delta Date
FROM  panel
WHERE (lower(criteria) LIKE lower(\'%criteria1%\'));
```